# DeadlineExceededException and DataStore/Task Queue Operations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm doing some operations that should complete under 60 seconds but there may be some rare cases where it takes longer (but will never take longer than 10 minutes). It says in the app engine docs if you catch a DeadlineExceededException you have less than a second to do operations before it permanently fails. Would this be enough time to add a task to a queue and/or do a datastore write? I assume the safest way would be to add a task async/write a datastore entity (async) at the beginning of an operation and remove it from the queue if the operation completes. The latter method would use up twice as many api calls but is it worth it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the queue as default for all operations so you won't have to implement the fallback to it if you catch a dead line exceed error. It is more clean and easier to maintain along with the fact that the user doesn't have to wait for the operation to complete. In order to achieve this you can trigger your queue with an ajax call and get the result in the background, so the user will not wait for the operation to complete. Yes it worth's it, since it can "guarantee" the window of time you might need.

Comment: My concern is continually poll the server to check if the queue completed. What I'm doing is having the client hit the server, it will first check the datastore to see if a cached version of the operation exists, if it exists return that. If not I will then generate the response dynamically, cache it to the datastore, and return it. Most of these responses can generate in under 60 seconds but its possible that some could take longer. I was hoping I could limit the amount of server polling by only queuing a response if necessary. Whats the time guarantee of the queue? How often would I poll?

Answer (score 1):

The runtime environment gives the request handler a little bit more time (less than a second) after raising the exception to prepare a custom response. so it would be sufficient to add that it into task queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the client to keep polling for a task queue result, I suggest you have a look at the Channel API. It will enable you to implement push notifications to the client.

At the end of your task queue, you'll just have to send a notification to the client to let him now that is task has been processed.